# Where CSC Compiler Generate PE file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, msbuild, csc

Take for an example, in Command Prompt we give as,

```
 >csc /out:"C:\HelloWorld.exe" "C:\HelloWorld.cs"
```

Than CSC Compiler will generate PE File. Where that file  will Save?

Comment: You said where you want the PE file: in `C:\Helloworld.exe`. The C# compiler does not generate an IL file; that's ILDASM that generates IL files. I cannot figure out what you are asking here; you seem to have some false beliefs about what files are generated by the C# compiler.

Comment: Downvoters . may i know the reason for downvoate?

Comment: Eric Lippert :  I want to knw where pe file will save while build .cs file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXE in [PE executable format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)  will be where you specify with `out` parameter or in current folder if you don't.

Not sure what "IL" file you are talking about, but IL (or rather byte code) + metadata are part of EXE file.

If you need details on PE format itself - specification can be found on MSDN: [PE Format](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=84140).

If you are looking for IL you may use ILDASM (part of .Net SDK) or many other .Net decompilers to see IL. If you want to quickly experiment and see IL - [LinqPad.net](http://www.linqpad.net/) is very convenient tool for that.

Comment: May i know command for generate pe file. because there is no pe file generating while giving above mentioned command

Comment: @Karthikeyan: The .EXE files is a PE file. PE stands for "portable executable". An EXE is an executable.

Comment: So while compiling .pe File will not generate only .exe will generate. right ?

Comment: @Karthikeyan if you link to what ".pe" file you expect it it would be easier to see what you are looking for. You can name output files  any way you want (including "HelloWorld.pe"), but CSC will only produce DLL/EXE (in PE format). I've added couple links to the post which may help to clarify what everyone reads from your question (may not exactly match what you wanted to know).